# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant when using aws java sdk

Tags: aws-sdk

I am getting error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils.<clinit>(ServiceUtils.java:67)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1265)
```

I am using below dependency for aws sdk :

```
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.10.30"
```

I am using 1.10.11 version for aws java sdk

Please suggest me, how can i overcome this issue ?

Comment: Did you solved it? I'm 4 years later in v1.11.886 and still a problem...

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. Actually i am using latest version (1.10.11) of aws-java-sdk and in latest version, joda time dependency has been removed. When i used earlier version (1.8.2), then it worked.

So if you want to use latest version of aws-java-sdk, then you have to add joda time dependency explicitly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're missing `joda-time` dependency as well.

Add it to your dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.2"
```